# Is the following function uniformly continuous on the closed and bounded interval?

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

Let us consider the identity function
$$f:(\mathbb{R},d)\to (\mathbb{R},d_{usual}) $$  $$f:x \to x$$
Here we are considering $d(x,y)=|(x)^3-(y)^3|$

Is the function $f$ uniformly continuous on closed and bounded interval?

I am looking for an example of function $f$ which is not uniformly continuous on a closed and bounded interval but it is continuous.

Comment: Any continuous function on a closed bounded interval is uniformly continuous.

Comment: That is in R under usual metric.What if the metric is different?

Comment: Any continuous function on a compact metric space into any metric space is uniformly continuous.

Comment: If you are using the metric $d$ on the domain also you should specify it. Also, a closed and bounded interval is compact in the metric $d$ also.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy do you think my current example willl work?

Comment: No. It doesn't. On a closed and bounded interval $x^{1/3}$ is continuous hence also uniformly continuous. That makes your map uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I assume that $\tan^{-1}$ denotes the arctangent $\arctan$.

No, your example does not work, because $\arctan$ is Lipschitz continuous. Indeed for all $x, y \in \Bbb R$
$$|\arctan x - \arctan y| \le |x-y|$$

this implies that the identity map $f: \Bbb R \to ( \Bbb R , d)$ is Lipschitz (hence uniformly continuous).

Anyway, if you want to build an example of a continuous function which is not uniformly continous on a closed and bounded interval, you are trying to find a counterexample to Heine-Cantor theorem. In particular you need to find a distance defined on the real line with the property that closed and bounded intervals are not compact.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the example?

Comment: How about $(R,d_{usual}) \to (R,d)$ where $d(x,y)=|x^3-y^3|$. Will this work if I take $f(x)=x$?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I don't think so, but now I have to leave, sorry